# I have made a lua calculator to learn the language but when i run the code it skips an io.read

Tags: lua

```
function CALC()
    print("First number:")
    local input1 = io.read("*n")
    print("operator: ")
    local operator = io.read("*l")
    print("secondNumber:")
    local input2 = io.read("*n")
    local switchCalc = {
        ["+"] = function ()
            local result = input1 + input2
            print(result)
        end,
        ["-"] = function ()
            local result = input1 - input2
            print(result)
        end,
        ["*"] = function ()
            local result = input1 * input2
            print(result)
        end,
        ["/"] = function ()
            local result = input1 / input2
            print(result)
        end
    }
    local a = 1
    local f = switchCalc[a]
    if(f) then
        f()
    else
        print("Default")
    end
end

CALC()
```

My output is: 
First number: `10` 
operator: 
secondNumber: 
`*` 
Default 
Hope somebody will help me with this cause I'm starring this from a couple hours and I really don't understand

Comment: Never use `io.read("*n")` - use `io.read("*n", "*l")` instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is not "the code skipping an `io.read`" as you make it out to be - it is simply you not using the variables correctly; the **reading is just fine**.

The line `local f = switchCalc[a]` uses a global variable `a` which you haven't defined (and which certainly isn't the operator). It will thus be `nil`. `switchCalc[nil]` is again `nil`, so `f` will be `nil`. Now the `if` doesn't trigger, the `else` is entered and you get "Default" as the output. The fix is simple: Just make this `switchCalc[operator]`.

Two notes:

- You don't need parentheses around `if`-conditions if you use spacing;
- `io.read()` is the same as `io.read("*l")` (you can omit `"*l"`)

Comment: Thanks it worked by changing the `swtichCalc[a]` to `swtichCalc[operator]`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use io.read() without any argument.
Also it looks more like a prompt if using io.write()
But converting it into whats asking for on the fly...

```
-- calc.lua (Tested with Lua 5.4)
local function calc()
io.write("First number: ") local input1 = tonumber(io.read()) -- number
io.write("Operator: ") local operator = io.read() -- Let a string be a string
io.write("Second number: ") local input2 = tonumber(io.read()) -- number
print('Equals to:', load('return '.. input1 .. operator .. input2)())
end

return calc
```

And than...

```
> calc = require('calc')
> calc()
First number: 3
Operator: *
Second number: 3
Equals to: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

How much I know:

```lua
print("First number:") -- prints -> First number:
local input1 = io.read("*n") -- when you write 10 , buffer got "10(enter)"
-- now buffer is "(enter)"
print("operator: ") -- prints -> operator:
local operator = io.read("*l") -- buffer not empty then operator is "(enter)"
print("secondNumber:")
local input2 = io.read("*n") -- try to read "*"
```

solution is add `io.read("*l")` before `print("operator: ")` or use io.read() not `io.read("*n")` / `io.read("*l")`

Comment: It makes sense but the problem is that I'm using vs code and every variable that is used is a brighter color than operators. That means that is not used. I also tryed adding `io.read("*l")` before the operator print and it still doesn't work. Thanks for the help anyways.